# How to tell users that they have to change the focus from the input to apply the change

Tags: input, input-focus

In HTML, if you have an input with an `onchange`, it doesn't register the change until you leave (or lose focus) that input. There's an `onKeyUp` function as well which would have the function run as they type. In my case, this input is affecting a graph that can be quite large at times, and typing in `1000`, would have to render the graph for `1`, `10`, `100`, then `1000` very quickly which can slow down the browser quite a bit.

So the problem is when a user types in `1000`, nothing changes until they leave the input, press enter or tab. What are some ways that I can tell them this? An 'apply' button seems a bit excessive at times if there are many inputs.

Answer (score 1):

`onchange` is too slow, `onkeyup` is too fast -- fortunately there is a middle ground, which doesn't require pestering the user with a notification: debounce the input events.

Essentially what this means is that you set the event to trigger on both keyup and blur, but limit the speed at which repeated triggers are taken into account: on receiving a new event, if an event already fired within the last *n* milliseconds, wait before firing to see if there are more events coming.  After the time has elapsed you can assume that the user has finished typing and go ahead and trigger the rerender based  on the last event.

One easy-to-use javascript implementation is [this](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function):

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Which you would use like so (in jQuery for example):

```
$('input.foo').on('change keyup', function() {
    debounce(function() {
      // rerender your graph here
    });
}, 250); // fire at most every 250ms. Adjust to taste
```

...but if that doesn't do it for you there are plenty of implementations to be found by searching "debounce".

Comment: This is good, but it doesn't address my question of how to tell users that they need to leave the input to commit the change. I won't always be able to edit javascript.

Comment: right, but with this technique they -don't- need to leave the input field to commit the change.

Comment: How would you do it if you can't edit the code?

Comment: I guess I'd talk to whoever on the product team does have that ability?

Comment: I've done that, they can't. Hence the question that I asked.

Comment: Well, if they can put in an event handler, there's no plausible technical reason they can't also include code to debounce that handler. So I'm not sure what to tell you.

Comment: This is also for .NET code. I only included the reference to javascript in my question because it's more familiar and helped me to explain the problem.

Comment: debounce isn't javascript-specific; it's a technique applicable to any kind of event-based code.      I don't mean to harp on this too much but I think you've set yourself up with an XY problem here: you're asking how best to notify the user that they need to do something, when there's a relatively simple way to set it up such that they don't need to do that thing in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try using events like 'OnKeyPress' in JavaScript.
I believe you are calling JS functions to send the input data to the Graph values.

Comment: I mention in my question that that's not really an option. `onkeyup` and `onkeypress` act in similar ways in this situation.

Comment: Then better will be to use JS Frameworks like JQuery, Angular JS etc., if you are not using already.

Comment: @sagar, Angular (or jQuery for only one feature) might as well be an overkill. Using a large framework or a library doesn't always have to be better.

Comment: Just this: [Have You Tried Using jQuery?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492)

Comment: @maxathousand nice one. My question only remotely mentions javascript. I'm looking for a way to inform the user how to leave the field, not rewrite my code base.